# C# How to geocode an address

Tags: c#, geocoding

I am using this to geocode an address

```
var address = "123 something st, somewhere";
var requestUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");
```

This seems to work but on closer observation I found it is not working.

For example, if I enter a valid address, it will geocode it fine.
But if I enter not valid address, sometimes it will still geocode it fine and result will have some other address.

For example, if I provide for address "`kl13jk5`" it will not geocode it and response will be null.  That is what would expect as the address "`kl13jk5`" is not valid.

However, If I enter "`kl13jk5 denver`", I will get response with an formatted address such as `<formatted_address>DENVER CO, USA</formatted_address>` but I would expect to get null as "`kl13jk5 denver`" is not a valid address.

What is wrong with my code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with your code, google returns the approximate address when it can't find the exact location. You can check the result if you want to know if it's an excat match or not. Check the value of `location_type`, it'll have values `GEOMETRIC_CENTER`, 'APPROXIMATE', etc. from which you can tell if google's guessing it or found the actual address. [check location_type here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results)
 There's also `partial_match`

Comment: Yes but if address is not valid, the location_type will be null, so NullReference exception is thrown

Comment: @dbnex14 Well if it's null then the address doesn't exist at all. If it's not null then you can check the location_type and partial_match.

Comment: At the Google Geocoding link (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), I can see explanation waht partial_match is but the provided XML (or Json) have no partial_match in them

Comment: @dbnex14 `xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result").Element("partial_match")`